# How to display DIV popup on Gridview row click event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I am using a web page which contains a grid view with the list of datas in that. I want to display the selected grid view row details into a popup or dialogue window on row click event.For that I have created one DIV and design it with proper control values. But I am not able to display the DIV on row click event.

Here is my Source code:

```
<div id="divPopup" runat="server" style="border:1px solid black;display:none ">
<fieldset>
<legend>Disabling User Account</legend>
<table style="height: 112px; font-weight: 700; font-size: medium; font-family: Cambria; color: #000000; width: 316px">

<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblGlobalId1" runat="server" Text="Global ID" />
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblGlobalIdValue1" runat="server" Text="80007929" />
</td>
</tr>
 .......
 .......
  <asp:Button ID="btnContinue1" runat="server" Height="26px" style="font-weight: 700" 
       Text="Continue" Width="92px" />
</table>
</fieldset>

</div>
```

.aspx Code is,

```
protected void grdADActionList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grdADActionList.Rows)
        {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.background='#eeff00';";

        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.background='#ffffff';";

        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdADActionList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
    }

protected void grdADActionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)            
    {

        //lblGlobalIDValue.Text = "278900078";
        //lblGivenNameValue.Text = "Surya";
        //lblEmailValue.Text = "surya@abc.com";

        divPopup.Visible = true;

    }
```

On page load event I am disabling that DIV visibility and on SelectedIndexChanged event I am enabling the DIV control visibility but the DIV control could not appear on the page. Can you please let me know How can i display the DIV popup control on my page? also I want to display it on the page center.

Please suggest me about the problem and tell me the solution for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your actual Asp.NET code.
I also noticed your popup div does not has a closing tag </div>

Comment: @UsamaKhalil: Its there...

Comment: Have you set the height and width properties of your div? A div with visibility = true and width = 0, height = 0 will not be rendered on the client

Comment: @Chrisi: I have set the height and width of the Div and I can able to display the DIV on my web page. But I want to display that DIV on the page center.. How can i set the position for that? Please help me...

Comment: @Suryakavitha: First thing that comes to my mind are the css properties margin. try setting it for all 4 attributes (top, left, bottom, right) to auto

Comment: @Chrisi: I have tried with CSS properties its working now. I have resolved my problem and I can view my DIV as a popup on my web page. Thank you so much.